# How to calculate the complexity of summation

Tags: computational-complexity

I am trying to calculate the computation complexity of an algorithm and I have reached the following summation (that shows the number of operations) and I don't know how to find the Big O. (H is a constant value > 2)
[image]

```
Sum[H^n*(1/2)^((n*(n - 1))/2), {n, 0, Infinity}](*you may edit if is true*)
```

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code.

Comment: If the sum counts the number of operations then it is a finite value. So I don't think n should go to infinity.

Comment: You can make a plot like `Plot[{Sum[H^n/2^((1/2)*(-1 + n)*n), {n, 0, 10}]}, {H, 0, 20}]`. An analytic result will be difficult to obtain.

Comment: If `H=1` or `H=1/2` we can get answer with: `EllipticTheta` function.

Comment: Building on the comment by @Andreas, a numerical solution is ``sum[h_] := NSum[h^n*(1/2)^((n*(n - 1))/2), {n, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the convergence value of summation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249381/calculating-the-convergence-value-of-summation)

Answer (score 4):

A good approximation to the exact result will be given by

```
QPochhammer[1/2,1/2]*QPochhammer[-(1/(2*H)),1/2]*QPochhammer[-H,1/2]
```

as can be seen in the plot:

```
Plot[{Sum[(Sqrt[2]*H)^n*(1/Sqrt[2])^n^2, {n, 0, 100}], 
 QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]*QPochhammer[-(1/(2*H)), 1/2]*
 QPochhammer[-H, 1/2]}, 
{H, 1, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}, AxesLabel -> {"H"}]
```

[image]

Calculate

```
Sum[z^(2*k)*q^k^2, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

and notice that the part of the sum with negative k is small for large H.

Edit:

In case you 'don't like' the QPochhammers the result may be expressed as a single EllipticTheta like

```
Sum[H^n/2^((1/2)*(-1 + n)*n),{n, 0, 10}]=
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[2]]*E^((Log[2]+2*Log[H])^2/(8*Log[2]))*
EllipticTheta[3,(Pi/2+(Pi*Log[H])/Log[2]),E^(-((2*Pi^2)/Log[2]))]
```

where `=`is to be understood as approximately equal...

Edit 2:

As we are dealing with an approximation: the value of the EllipticTheta function is very close to 1 over all the range, so it can be ignored and we are left with a simple exponential function! To see the error at small H do a  LogLogPlot:

```
LogLogPlot[{Sum[H^n/2^((1/2)*(-1 + n)*n), {n, 0, 10}], 
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[2]]*E^(Log[Sqrt[2]*H]^2/Log[4])}, {H, 1, 200}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}, AxesLabel -> {"H"}]
```

Comment: what is QPochhammer?

Comment: @Arash it is the q-analog to the Pochhammer function, a ratio of Gamma functions. You can look it up in the Mathematica documentation

Comment: Could you please see my new question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249381/calculating-the-convergence-value-of-summation