# Calculating the convergence value of summation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, convergence

Could you please tell me what value the left side of the inequality converges to?

`(H and P are constant values greater than 2 and n can go to infinity)`

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}{\left(H^n*\left(\frac{1}{P}\right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\right)}\leq \alpha$$

I know that according to d'Alembert's ratio test the left side of inequality will converge to some value. as shown below:
[image]

Update: Thanks to @user64494 for the 3d plot I have another question

`Plot3D[NSum[H^n*(1/P)^(n*(n - 1)/2), {n, 1, Infinity}], {H, 2, 50}, {P, 2, 100}]`

How can I change the out range? it only draws 0 to 200,
[image]

Comment: Can you, please, post what work (WL code) you have done so far to solve this question? It is helpful, too, if you can note what problems you are having with that code. Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you for your comment, all I want to do is plot it and find a parametric value of convergence, like: Plot[{Sum[H^n*(1/p)^(n*(n-1)/2), {n, 1, Infinity}]]

Comment: Hi Arash! Thanks for this extra information; can you, please, update your question with such details? Namely, it should be more convenient for those who wish to help to answer your question if you include the WL code that will make the equations that you have written. That is, it should not be expected that a potential answerer will read your equations & format them into code, so it is better that you do this and include it in your question.

Comment: Take look at the result of `Plot3D[NSum[H^n*(1/P)^(n*(n - 1)/2), {n, 1, Infinity}], {H, 2, 4}, {P,
   2, 4}]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you, It worked, Do you know how to add another plane to the same 3dplot? like (out=2) and find the finding the intercept between these two planes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this time a little more explicit:

Mathematica calculates exactly

```
Sum[z^(2*k)*q^k^2,{k, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* QPochhammer[q^2,q^2]*QPochhammer[-(q/z^2),q^2]*QPochhammer[(-q)*z^2,q^2] *)
```

which is equal to

```
EllipticTheta[3, -I Log[z],E^(-Pi \[Lambda])] = (E^(Log[z]^2/(Pi*\[Lambda]))*
EllipticTheta[3, -(Log[z]/\[Lambda]), E^(-(Pi/\[Lambda]))])/Sqrt[\[Lambda]]
```

(to see this use q = E^(-Pi/[Lambda]) and replace  EllipticTheta with its product representation). The right side of the equation expresses the left side in completely real terms.

If z is large enough (z>=2) and q is small enough (q<= 0.2) the sum is approximately equal to

```
Sum[z^(2*k)*q^k^2, {k, 0, Infinity}].
```

Then replace

```
 {z -> Sqrt[H*Sqrt[P]], q -> 1/Sqrt[P]}
```

to get  the result as shown in the Plot

```
H = 3; Plot[{Sum[H^k*(1/P)^((k^2 - k)/2), {k, -10, 10}], 
Sum[H^k*(1/P)^((k^2 - k)/2), {k, 0, 10}], 
EllipticTheta[3, (-I)*(1/2)*(Log[H] + Log[P]/2), 1/Sqrt[P]], 
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[P]]*E^(Log[P*H^2]^2/(8*Log[P]))*
EllipticTheta[3, (Pi*(-Log[H] - Log[P]/2))/Log[P], 
E^(-((2*Pi^2)/Log[P]))], 
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[P]]*E^(Log[P*H^2]^2/(8*Log[P]))}, {P, 2, 100}, 
AxesLabel -> {"P"}]
```

[image: result]

There are five functions superimposed, two sums from +-Infinity and 0 to Infinity, EllipticTheta with Imaginary argument and without, and the result without EllipticTheta (value is about 1). All agree to a good approximation. You can choose which ones to use... The best agreement you'll get with EllipticTheta included, but the Exponential may be good enough.

I'll add a 3D Plot of the one sided sum and the Exponential:

```
Plot3D[{Sum[H^k*(1/P)^((k^2 - k)/2), {k, 0, 100}], 
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[P]]*E^(Log[P*H^2]^2/(8*Log[P]))}, {P, 2, 100}, 
{H, 2, 50}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: 3D Plot]

You can adjust the displayed height with PlotRange.

And to see the approximation here is the difference:

```
Plot3D[{Sum[H^k*(1/P)^((k^2 - k)/2), {k, 0, 100}] - 
Sqrt[(2*Pi)/Log[P]]*E^(Log[P*H^2]^2/(8*Log[P]))}, {P, 2, 100}, 
{H, 2, 50}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: difference]

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following answers your question.

```
RegionPlot[NSum[H^n*(1/P)^(n*(n - 1)/2), {n, 1, Infinity}] <= 10, {H,2,4},{P, 2, 4}]
```

[image]